# Read Excel-files from .NET

Tags: .net, excel, import

I'm looking for a **free class or example to read data from a closed Excel-file**. I have a full file path (as String) at hand which can be passed to the class reading the data from that file.

I'd like to be able do some validation before trying to read the data:

- Check how many worksheets and their names
- On each worksheet how many rows contain data
- If possible, read metadata/custom document properties from the file

I'm concerned, if OldeDb used, how it works with all Excel versions (2003,2007,2010 etc).

Is there anything out there that can do these things safely?

Comment: What do you mean by "closed"?

Comment: By closed, I mean the Excel file to read is not open when it is read (as opposed to first open the file, do the reading, then closing the file).

Comment: Can you rely on Excel being installed on the computer?

Comment: Yes, I can rely on Excel being installed on the user's computer. Excel version may however vary.